# Django model order by model method or calculation on model fields

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-filter

I have a `Django Model`, `OrderItem`

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
   order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='order_line')
   quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   order_number = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Order Number')
   order_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   dispatch_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
   cancel_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I have a model function that calculates the days between today and the OrderItem `order_date` or `dispatch_date` and `order_date`

```
    def get_aging(self):
        today = datetime.today().date()
        if self.dispatch_date is not None:
            aging = self.dispatch_date - self.order_date
            return aging.days
        elif self.cancel_date is not None:
            return 0
        else:
            aging = today - self.order_date
            return aging.days
```

I want to order the `OrderItems` by the same calc. I have tried to use the python sort but I can't apply the `django FilterSet` on the list created by the python sorted method. This is the code in my view, I am using a custom template as I allow for inline editing of the data.

```
order_qs = OrderItem.objects.all()
sorted_qs sorted(order_qs, key= lambda a: a.get_aging())
user_filter_orders = OrderItemsFilter(request.GET, queryset=order_qs)
```

The error because of the sorted method returning a list:
`list` object has no attribute `model`

Any suggestions, please?

Answer (score 0):

Change the execution order of your instruction, instead of filter then sort, filter first then sort

```py
    order_qs = OrderItem.objects.all()
    user_filter_orders = OrderItemsFilter(request.GET, queryset=order_qs)
    sorted_qs = sorted(user_filter_orders, key= lambda a: a.get_aging())
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't  work as the OrderItemFilter isn't iterate.